Polynomial ring $R[x]$ is hypercentral if and only if $R$ is hypercentral ring
Let $R$ be a commutative ring then $R[x]$ is commutative ring, it is obvious.
Now define hypercenter as $T(R)=\lbrace a\in R | ab^n=b^na ,n=n(b,a)\ge 1, \forall b\in R\rbrace$
If all elements of $R$ satisfy this property, does it means that all elements of $R[x]$ also satisfy it, means $f(x)(g(x))^n=(g(x))^nf(x)$ for all $f(x),g(x)$ in $R[x]$.

If $a$ has to commute with $x^n$ for all $n \ge 1$ and for all $x$, then in particular it has to commute with $x^1$ for all $x$, so $a$ commutes with the whole of $R$. From your description it looks like $T(R)$ is just the centre of $R$.

No, it is not for all $n$, actually $n$ depends on $x$, for different $x$ some fixed $n$ exits, so it is not a whole center

@Chaudhary You should edit the question to make your definition of $T(R)$ clear. It sounds like it's the set of $a \in R$ such that for all $x \in R$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ such that $a x^n = x^n a$. It's also not a great idea to use the same notation $x$ for the variable of the polynomial ring $R[x]$, and for an arbitrary element of $R$ as in your definition of $T(R)$.

Done @ViktorVaughn

Does it seem good now @ViktorVaughn

So your question is: if $T(R) =R$, does that imply $T(R[x])=R[x]$ ?

Yes actually, thank you @FrançoisGatine to make it simple

The rng $$R=\left{\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&a&c\0&0&b\0&0&0                       \end{array}  \right)\vert,, a,b,c\in  \mathbb{Z}\right}$$ is a counterexample.  Let $$e_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&1&0\0&0&0\0&0&0 \end{array}  \right),\qquad e_2=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&0\0&0&1\0&0&0 \end{array}  \right), \qquad e_3=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&1\0&0&0\0&0&0                       \end{array}  \right).  $$  Then $e_2(x+e_1)^n=x^n e_2$, whilst $(x+e_1)^ne_2=x^ne_2+nx^{n-1}e_3$.  However this $R$ is not a ring, so probably does not help with your question,

$n$ can be any positive integer or $n\ge 3$ @tkf

@Chaudhary Not sure what you mean.  In the example above, all elements of $R$ are hypercentral, but $e_2\in R[x]$ is not hypercentral, as $e_2(x+e_1)^n\neq(x+e_1)^ne_2$ for all positive integers $n$.  Not sure what you meant about $n\geq 3$.

Thanks.  I got it @tkf

Of course $R$ is not a ring.  You can throw in the identity $I_3$ to $R$, and work over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, to get a hypercentral ring $R'$.  The problem is that $R'[x]$ is now also hypercentral.
